# How to write a sql code to count multiple value in a row

Tags: sql

I have a data like below

```
Id  | Country  
----+----------------------------
1   | India 
2   | India|United kingdom|Chile
3   | Brazil
4   | Mexico|Canada 
5   | China|Hong kong|Japan
```

The mapping of country and region  is in a temporary table called reg

```
Country.        | Region 
----------------|------------
India           | Apac
United kingdom  | Emea
Chile           | Latam
Canada          | Canada 
Mexico          | Latam
 China          | Apac
Hong kong       | Apac 
Japan           | Apac
```

I want to write a code to show region against Ids. If the ID is having multiple countries of different regions then show Multiple region . If the ID has Multiple countries but the region is same for all countries then show only that region not Multiple region for that ID else show one region like below

Need output like below:

```
Id. |  Region 
----+------------------
1   |  Apac
2   |  Multiple region
3   |  Latam
4   |  Multiple region
5   |  Apac
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`,etc..) that you are using.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values in a single column to begin with.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. This problem is a symptom of a poorly thought out, denormalised data structure. A better idea would be to normalise the data structure, and then this kind of string-processing issue will not arise.

Comment: Yes agree but we have data like that coming from system . I did try to normalise and the output after normalization is like below.

Comment: ID  Country 
1 India
2 India
2 United Kingdom
2 Chile
3 Brazil
4 Mexico 
4 Canada

Comment: If your data is coming from another system and being imported into your database, you should ideally normalise it at the time you import it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use case statement in your join. Here is the example

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    countryName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Country(id, countryName)
VALUES(1,'India'),
    (2,'India|United kingdom|Chile'),
    (3,'Brazil'),
    (4,'Mexico|Canada');


CREATE TABLE Region (
    countryName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    regionName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);


INSERT INTO Region(countryName, regionName)
VALUES('India','Apac'),('United kingdom','Emea'),('Chile','Latam'),('Canada','Canada'),('Mexico','Latam'),('China','Apac'),
('Hong kong','Apac'),('Japan','Apac'),('Brazil','Lathem')

Select C.Id, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',C.CountryName) > 0 
     THEN 'Multiple Region' 
     ELSE R.RegionName 
     END as Region 
from Country [C]
LEFT JOIN Region[R] ON [C].countryName = [R].countryName
```

Key here is left join and case statement where you will find | in column value then you return as multiple region.

Comment: Thanks Sachin . The code worked but when the country is in same region for that ID it is showing Multiple region . If the ID belong to multiple countries but thoses countries are in one region then I just want region name like APAC EMEA etc else show multiple region .Id  Country
5 China|Hong kong|Japan
6 India|Hong Kong
 
 
 
Output : 
 
ID  
5 APAC 
6 APAC

Comment: Apologies, I think i misunderstood your requirement. Can you explain in detail with sample output in your original question. This will help others to understand your question properly too. I will try to solve it again.

Comment: Id  Country
1 India
2 India|United Nations|Chile
3 Brazil
4 Mexico|Canada
5 China|Hong kong|Japan
6 India|Hong Kong
 
 
 
Output : 
 
ID  
1 APAC
2 Multiple
3 LATAM
4 Multiple
5 APAC 
6 APAC

Comment: how come brazil has region LATAM ?

Comment: Brazil comes under LATAM region . Its a dummy data .

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need to split the values, you could get away with something like this:

```
select d.id, coalesce(r.region, 'Multiple regions') as region
from data_table d
  left join regions r on r.country = d.country;
```

The rows that contain multiple entries won't match during the join (that's why an outer join is needed).

The drawback is, that you can't distinguish between a missing country and an entry with multiple countries in the result though.

If you need to distinguish between missing countries and multiple countries, you can do that in a CASE expression:

```
select d.id, 
       d.country,
       case 
         when d.country like '%|%' then 'Multiple regions'
         else r.region 
       end as region
from data_table d
  left join region r on r.country = d.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of Like and Join , something like this

```
SELECT cnt.id,
CASE WHEN cnt.country like '%|%' then 'Multiple region' 
 else map.region
 END region
from 
(
Select  1 id,   'India' as country union all
Select 2,     'India|United kingdom|Chile' union all
Select 3,   'Brazil' union all
Select 4,  'Mexico|Canada' 
 ) cnt
Left Join  
(
Select 'India'  as country ,          'Apac' as region union all
Select 'United kingdom',   'Emea' union all
Select 'Chile',            'Latam' union all
Select 'Canada',           'Canada'  union all
Select 'Mexico',           'Latam' union all
Select  'China',              'Apac' union all
Select 'Hong kong',     'Apac'  union all
Select 'Japan' ,            'Apac'
  ) map on cnt.country =map.country






'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` and aggregation:

```
select d.id, d.country,
       (case when min(r.region) <> max(r.region)
             then 'Multiple regions'
             else min(r.region) 
        end) as region
from data_table d left join
     region r
     on r.country like '%|' || d.country || '|%'
group by d.id, d.country;
```

Note that this uses the standard string concatenation operator.  Your database might have a different method.

As discussed in the comments, you should fix the data model!  Storing multiple values in a string column is a very bad idea in relational databases.