# how to write a SQL code to show categorise the data values

Tags: sql

I have data like below :

```
ID           Country 

1            India
2            Hongkong 
2            United Kingdom
3            Chile
3            Hong Kong
4            Singapore
```

Region Table is a temporary table which is having data like below:

```
 Country              Region

 India                APAC
 Hongkong             APAC 
 United Kingdom       EMEA
 Chile                LATAM
 Hong Kong            APAC
 Singapore            APAC
```

If the Country belongs to the same region show the region name else show Multiple regions if the ID has different regions

Output :

```
ID           Region

1            APAC
2            Multiple Region
3            Multiple Region
4            APAC
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389905/how-to-write-a-sql-code-to-count-multiple-value-in-a-row

Answer (score 0):

Either try `Union` or try `row_number()` as one of the other answers which is easy straight forward as `row_number()` doesnt reduces the number of rows as in `group by` but depends on the database and version for `row_number()` sometimes.

```
  Select id, "MULTIPLE 
   REGIONS" 
    from table t1 join temp t2
    on t1.country=t2.country
    Group by id having
   count(distinct 
   region) >=1
    Union
    (Select id, region
    from table t1 join temp t2
    on t1.country=t2.country
    Group by id having

   count(distinct 
   region) =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` the tables.

Do a `GROUP BY`.

Use a `case` expression to return the region name if there's only one distinct region, otherwise return 'multiple regions'.

(Assuming table 1 is called countries)

```
select c.id,
       case when count(distinct r.Region) = 1 then max(r.Region)
            else 'Multi regions'
       end
from countries c
join regions r on c.Country = r.Country
group by c.id
```

**EDIT:**

Will execute as:

```
SQL>create table countries(ID int, Country varchar(25));
SQL>insert into countries values (1, 'India');
SQL>insert into countries values (2, 'Hongkong');
SQL>insert into countries values (2, 'United Kingdom');
SQL>insert into countries values (3, 'Chile');
SQL>insert into countries values (3, 'Hong Kong');
SQL>insert into countries values (4, 'Singapore');
SQL>
SQL>create table regions(Country  varchar(25), Region varchar(25));
SQL>
SQL>insert into regions values ('India', 'APAC');
SQL>insert into regions values ('Hongkong', 'APAC ');
SQL>insert into regions values ('United Kingdom', 'EMEA');
SQL>insert into regions values ('Chile', 'LATAM');
SQL>insert into regions values ('Hong Kong', 'APAC');
SQL>insert into regions values ('Singapore', 'APAC');
SQL>
SQL>select c.id,
SQL&       case when count(distinct r.Region) = 1 then max(r.Region)
SQL&            else 'Multi regions'
SQL&       end
SQL&from countries c
SQL&join regions r on c.Country = r.Country
SQL&group by c.id;
         ID
=========== =========================
          1 APAC
          2 Multi regions
          3 Multi regions
          4 APAC

                  4 rows found
```

Comment: This is not working . It is still showing me the region with than multiple region . If the country is in APAC and LATAM then this code is showing APAC not multiple region.

Comment: @user5572765, see edit, isn't this what you've specified as wanted result?